# When to use "wherein" instead of "where"?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, legalese

I've came across the word "wherein", and I'm doubtful about how different it is from using just plain "where". For example in this sentence:

> There is a case, though, **wherein** you can use the aforementioned property.

Is there any difference in meaning if I use "where"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Wherein* means "in which place, situation or thing; in what way." It is a formal word that is almost equivalent to *where*.

> an organization wherein each employee is valued and respected

> an organization where each employee is valued and respected

Comment: So, their difference is just the more formal sense given by "wherein"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: kiam, is "wherein" translate or translable with "nell'ambito del quale": "an organization nell'ambito della quale each employee is valued and respected"?

Comment: @Carlo_R. You can use _nell'ambito della quale_, _nella quale_, or simply _dove_.

Comment: almost equivalent to 'where'? I'd like to discuss this.

Answer (score 21):

Not only is *wherein* a more archaic term, but it actually has a different meaning than *where*. [It means "in which"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wherein), and is primarily used as a flowery term evoking legal language, or a fancy or pretentious-sounding table of contents in a book. (e.g. "Chapter 2: Wherein Christopher Robin Meets a Heffalump and Pooh Does Not")

The grammatically correct substitution for *wherein* is "in which". Replacing *wherein* with *where* is one of those cases that is probably incorrect in a technical sense, but it's used enough that people will understand you and it won't sound unnatural.

I am not 100% sure of the etymology, but there is some similarity between some of the archaic English terms like *wherein* and *wherefore*, and German terms like [*worin*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/german-english/worin) and [*wofür*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/german-english/wof%C3%BCr). The *wo-* terms blindly translate as "where" + a preposition, but the actual correct translation for the *wo*-prefix is that preposition + "which". I suspect that the blind translation of the German *wo-* prefix into the English *where-* prefix is how we got these terms. See this English.SE question on [whereof/wherein/wherefrom/whereupon/wherewith/wherefore](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164651/whereof-wherein-wherefrom-whereupon-whereby-wherewith-wherefore-in-a-conte).

Comment: similarly for thereof/therein/therefore/thereupon/therewith/therefore and the *da-* prefix in German, for example dafür, darin.  (I've never heard of wherefrom or therefrom)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, they're not interchangeable. "wherein" refers to a preceding context and "where" does not. You can properly say "I threw the football to my son where my buddy threw a baseball to his son". You can't use "wherein" there. Similarly, if you say "a computer system rendering images where the processor used a jpeg format". This does not necessarily imply that the processor wasn't in another computer system processing another image. Here, the term "wherein" would necessarily mean that the processor was in the preceding computer system.

Answer (score 0):

I always choose to use "in which."
"Where" is used primarily for a place or location.

- I live in a house where there is peace and harmony.

I use "in which" for words such as dream, situation, or circumstance.

- That's a kind of situation in which anyone will feel awkward.